# Angular 12 : c.getComputedStyle is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, dom-to-image

I'm using the new [dom-to-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dom-to-image-more) lib and I'm facing this error when I try to call the `toPng` method inside of a component.

```
import domtoimage from 'dom-to-image-more';
export class MyComponent {
    @ViewChild('leafletMap') leafletMap: ElementRef;
    
    downloadMap = (): void => {
        //error happens here
        domtoimage.toPng(this.leafletMap.nativeElement).then((img: any) => {
            console.log(img);
        });
    };
}
/* of course this is simplified */
```

The leafletMap exists in my components HTML and when I log it, it contains a HtmlNativeElement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems there is an issue with the latest version of the lib. Try using this version:

```
"dom-to-image-more": "2.8.0"
```

I have created a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-leaflet-basic-7malkj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts), click on download button and see the result.

Comment: Wow, it works. I guess I'll file an issue on their repo then. Thanks for the deep debugging !